# Mermaid state diagram duplicating states

Tags: mermaid

I created a mermaid state diagram, in fact I'm trying to generate it, but I'm getting duplicate states in my diagram
this is the code

```
stateDiagram-v2

state s4 : Filling
{
p29 : Upload 
}

state s5 : Integration

state s6 : Process
{
p31 : Process internal
}


[*] --> s4 : Inicial
s4 --> s5 : Upload
s5 --> s4 :Not OK
s5--> [*] : End
```

and this is the result

[image]

shoudn't be just two states in the diagram and not have those s4 and s5 boxes?

Comment: As an FYI to anyone reading this in the future - this has been logged as a bug with MermaidJs, and is being tracked uynder https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/4053

Comment: In fact it's being tracked in this url https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/4061